# Is there a map of users?

Tags: discussion

Is there a map of users, something like a google map with pins?

Answer (score 4):

I created one [here](http://goo.gl/U4n1S6):

[image: Feb 2014 users map]

This only shows the 46.5% of 13,754 total users that have a location value. Several locations are just the country name, hence the larger blue circles in the middle of the various countries.

---

Unfortunately, it's not live, so we'd have to update it periodically (or find some heatmap map thing that can take in a CSV URL).

#### How to create the map:

1. Run Location Popularity query: http://data.stackexchange.com/diy/query/edit/170954
2. Download CSV
3. Upload to http://www.openheatmap.com/
4. I used these settings: [image]

Answer (score 3):

None that I'm aware of. And many users don't include their location in their profile, so any implementation would be partial at best.

Comment: geolocated IPs?

Comment: @Mikey - that would involve SE releasing information which could potentially identify individuals who would otherwise have remained anonymous. It's not something SE is ever going to do.

Comment: @ChrisF - not that I don't like to argue a point, but I'll abandon this.  Thanks all for putting up with my bad Q.

Comment: @Mikey it's not a bad question, just one that your not going to get an answer to that you'll like.

Comment: Agreed, nothing wrong with asking the question. IP's, email addresses, and other private user data are not released to the public by SE. And I agree with ChrisF that data extrapolated from private user data will likely be giving the same protections by SE.

Comment: Am I the only that is curious about this? DIY projects pretty regional in terms of jargon and viable techniques.  Just saying, but moving forward. Thanks again.

Comment: See http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/806/should-question-askers-be-required-to-state-their-location